# Parsing path string to find all ancestors using Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig

Given an input file containing paths and some other columns:

```
\aa\bb\cc         ... 
\aa\bb\cc\dd\ee   ...
\xx\yy\zz         ...
```

I'm looking for way in HiveQL to explode the paths to a distinct list including all the ancestor paths as well. For the sample above the result should be:

```
\aa
\aa\bb
\aa\bb\cc
\aa\bb\cc\dd
\aa\bb\cc\dd\ee
\xx
\xx\yy
\xx\yy\zz
```

Is there any way to do that in Hive without resorting to custom Java UDFs?

If not, how about in Pig?

Answer (score 0):

I woud think this is more of a mapreduce kind of problem, instead of a database one.  It seams like a good use of java string manipulation and loops.

Comment: I know how to do this in Java.  The question is whether it is possible using pure Hive or Pig.